# Count the number of occurances by escaping the delimiter in a special case

Tags: java

I have read the file content as String. Now i want to identify the number of occurances of a string..However it should not be followed by a question mark and we should ignore them.

Example

> Number of occurances found of $ = 1, In the below string

```
FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC?:??$HASCO UK LTS;?:V.D??$  TOUZA?:GB?:GB$
```

> Number of occurances found of $ = 2, In the below string

```
FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC?:??$HASCO UK LTS;?:V.D??$  TOUZA?:GB?:GB$ABCD$
```

> Number of occurances found of $ = 3, In the below string

```
FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC?:??$HASCO UK LTS;?:V.D??$  TOUZA?:GB?:GB$ABCD$PPP?$QQQQ$
```

Please let me know how to do this in java.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you tried so far? Please include a [mcve] of your code, and any issues you are currently facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
final String regex = "(?<!\\?)\\$";
final String string = "FTX+AAA+++201707141009UTC?:??$HASCO UK LTS;?:V.D??$ TOUZA?:GB?:GB$";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```